# How to copy data from one type to another that has identical structures?

Tags: go, pointers, struct, slice

In the below code:

```
type ProductEntity struct {
    ID          int     `json:"id"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Price       float32 `json:"price"`
    SKU         string  `json:"sku"`
    CreatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    DeletedOn   string  `json:"-"`
}

type ProductEntityList []*ProductEntity

type PostRequestModel struct {
    ID          int     `json:"id"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Price       float32 `json:"price"`
    SKU         string  `json:"sku"`
    CreatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedOn   string  `json:"-"`
    DeletedOn   string  `json:"-"`
}

type RequestBody []*PostRequestModel

func convertModelToEntity(modelList RequestBody) ProductEntityList {

    // return entity.ProductEntityList(modelList) // type conversion error 

}
```

---

How to copy data from one type to another, that has identical structures? Because `RequestBody` and `ProductEntityList` are two different type definitions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If those type are truly equal, use [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

```
type PostRequestModel = ProductEntity
```

If you do so, you can simply convert from `ProductEntityList` to `RequestBody` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RhsonvWRcJG)):

```
func convertModelToEntity(modelList RequestBody) ProductEntityList {
    return ProductEntityList(modelList) // Works!!
}
```

If you can't use type alias, then you can't convert from one slice to another. You have to create a new slice. Note that you can convert the individual slice elements because the pointed struct types have identical fields. This is possible because [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - [...]
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` are pointer types that are not [defined types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), and their pointer base types have identical underlying types.

So `*ProductEntity` is convertible to `*PostRequestModel` (and vice versa) because the underlying type of `ProductEntity` and `PostRequestModel` is the "same" struct type.

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kwSul7wujPS):

```
func convertModelToEntity(modelList RequestBody) ProductEntityList {
    r := make(ProductEntityList, len(modelList))
    for i, m := range modelList {
        r[i] = (*ProductEntity)(m)
    }
    return r
}
```

Also note that if `RequestBody` and `ProductEntityList` have identical memory layout (they do in your example), you may use package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) to simply convert them, but I'd rather avoid it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4atahXAgVz9)):

```
func convertModelToEntity(modelList RequestBody) ProductEntityList {
    return *(*ProductEntityList)(unsafe.Pointer(&modelList))
}
```

Why to avoid this? Using package `unsafe` your app may become non-portable and the Go 1 compatibility guarantees may not apply to it. E.g. you may add a field to `ProductEntity` only but not to `PostRequestModel`. As a result, your app will continue to compile without errors, but may blow up at any time. Always look at package `unsafe` as the last resort.

Comment: For this line `(*ProductEntity)(m)`, conversion is possible, because of the rule mentioned in [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): `ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T have identical underlying types.`, Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, exaclty that.